# Add an <a> tag using WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning WordPress and was wondering if it's possible to add HTML code to just above the closing `body` tag using a WordPress plugin. What I'm trying to inject is an image hyperlink.

Comment: This question lack some information, have you tried anything ? You should consider reading the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) To make sure to create a well construct and answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following to your themes `functions.php` or your plugin code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_new_element' );

function add_new_element() {
    echo '<a href="google.com"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></a>';
}
```

It will insert the link before the closing `body` tag

Comment: Thanks!! What if i have a javascript code taht i want to add in the body tag

Comment: Thanks again,sorry i should have searched about the js it was easy to find taht

Comment: No worries, have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. [See more in WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)

```html
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_function()
{
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Reference: [wp_footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)

Hope this helps!